# python regular expression - searching in file for the pattern

Tags: python, regex

> Write a program that outputs only the words in `/usr/share/dict/words` that start with the letters "ply". It should output the words in order, each on their own line.

```
import re

with open('words.txt', 'r') as words:

  pattern = re.compile(r'^ply.*')

  matches = pattern.match(words)

  for the match in matches:
    print(match)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `^` is the start of string, not start of word. Try `\bply.*?\b`

Comment: @Sweeper Since the input is `/usr/share/dict/words`, which has one word per line, that isn't actually a problem here.

Comment: There are many things wrong with this code. (1) You open `words.txt` in the current directory, instead of `/usr/share/dict/words`. (2) You're trying to run a pattern over a file object. (3) You're using `match` instead of something like `finditer` or `findall`. That would work if you had a `for line in words:` and matched each `line`, but you're not doing that. (4) `for the match in matches:` is invalid syntax; you can't throw the word `the` in like that. (5) `match` returns a match object, which isn't something you can loop over. (6) You haven't attempted to handle the case where match fails.

Answer (score 0):

`match()` works if the RE matches at the beginning of the string, so you don't need extra `'^'` in RE. Assuming words file in the same folder as code, below code should work.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'ply.*')
with open('words.txt', 'r') as lines:
    for line in lines:
        if pattern.match(line):
            print(line)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following regex if you are not taking into account the case:

```
(?i)\bply[^\s]*
```

It gives the following output on my distro dict words file:

```
Plymouth
Plymouth's
ply
ply's
plying
plywood
plywood's
```

If the case matters, then use:

```
\bply[^\s]*
```

It gives the following output on my distro dict words file:

```
ply
ply's
plying
plywood
plywood's
```

**DISTRO:**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

The result might be different on your system.

You can add this regex in your `Python` code to have the following working sample:

```
$ more plywords.py
import re

#open the file with its full path and in read-only mode
with open('/usr/share/dict/words', 'r') as file:
  pattern = re.compile(r'(?i)\bply[^\s]*') #define the regex that you are going to use to analyse the text
  #for each line of your file, you fetch all the matches and loop on them via the inner loop; for each match found you print it.
  for line in file:
        for m in pattern.findall(line):
                print(m)
```

and running it:

```
$ python plywords.py 
Plymouth
Plymouth's
ply
ply's
plying
plywood
plywood's
```

Comment: Changing the regex in the OP's existing code doesn't fix any of the problems. Meanwhile, [there's nothing to fix in the regex](https://regex101.com/r/B0X7u8/1), so changing it is irrelevant.

Comment: @abarnert: I have edited my post and added a working sample! Regarding the regex indeed the only point might be the case

Comment: This still isn't a very useful answer. You replaced the OP's working regex for no reason, and then replaced the broken code with completely different code without explaining what you changed. How is this likely to help anyone, unless their goal is to turn in a homework assignment without understanding it?